# How to cancel an asynchronous HTTP request in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, asynchronous

I'm trying to add in the ability to cancel all current asynchronous requests when the user leaves the view or when they initiate a new request. I know where to put the code, but I'm not quite sure how to actually cancel the request. From my research, I know that `NSURLConnection` has a `cancel` method, but I'm calling my requests using asynchronous blocks. Below is my code - any help is greatly appreciated!

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[kEndpointEvents stringByAppendingString:arguments]]];

//Send an asynchronous request so it doesn't pause the main thread
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    //Do stuff

}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to cancel an ongoing request when using the convenience methods `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler` or `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`.

If you want cancellation, implement the methods in the delegate `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, and build the data yourself from the callbacks. Doing that will give you control over the connection object and you can call `-cancel` on it anytime.

Comment: Do you have a library, tutorial, or example you'd recommend?

Comment: Checkout https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577317/nsurlconnection-delegate-method, http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

Comment: Just FYI to anyone else wondering: After doing some research, I ended up using the AFNetworking library. It is a very well designed and up-to-date library that allows for connection cancelling and much more.

Comment: @rebello95, Could you still share some implementation for the library or how you finished solving the issue?

Comment: @kitimenpolku just look at their documentation and/or tutorials. There is a ton of info on it out there.